# When removing a bunch of files from a website, is 301 to the start page appropriate?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do with random pages after a 301 redirect?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9847/what-to-do-with-random-pages-after-a-301-redirect)

Currently, we are working on modifying the contents of a website of one of our products.

Since we are re-positioning the product, we would like to delete roughly 50% (around 200) of the pages of the website.

My questions, in terms of SEO are:

- Would it have a negative effect if Google suddenly sees the large page drop?
- Is it OK to provide a 301 to the start page of the website for all removed pages?

Comment: I read this "possible duplicate" entry you refer to, before posting. To me, I cannot see this as an answer. The refered posting wants to move pages, I just want to delete them. No help then for me?